# Add Webview to HomeScreen

Tags: flutter, flutterwebviewplugin, flutter-inappwebview

I'm opening a web URL inside a webview. How do I add the functionality of `Adding it to the HomeScreen` to webview?

I'm using [InAppWebview](https://inappwebview.dev/) to launch a webview. Using [ChromeSafariBrowser](https://inappwebview.dev/docs/chrome-safari-browser/basic-usage/) component, it gives a default option of `Adding to HomeScreen`. How can I build a similar functionality for webview?

For the uninitiated, I'm looking at this functionality.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is a javascript function which you can call to ask the user if he wants to add the current webpage to his homepage. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Progressive_web_apps/Add_to_home_screen.

In their docs:
https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_inappwebview/latest/flutter_inappwebview/JavaScriptReplyProxy-class.html

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking out for. I'll give it a try and revert. Thanks @Stan.

Comment: No problem, let me know if your attempt is succesful. Otherwise i will code up an example for you

Comment: @Stan does it show as a pop-up with your solution or do you still have to navigate to your iOS browsers preferences ?

Comment: I am not certain about that. Normally a browser will handle calls to specific functions. For example, the popup that is shown when the alert() function is called, does look somewhat different in every browser. A webview is basicly a virtual browser. Like all browsers, it parses HTML/CSS/JS. So the way it wil initiate the add to home function depends on how the team behind flutter_inappwebview implemented it.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are trying to ask how to add the webview to the Home Screen of your app.
You did not share your code for the Home Screen but I believe it is safe to say that everything in flutter is a widget and you are also currently using the InAppWebView Widget.

Their [documentation](https://inappwebview.dev/docs/in-app-webview/basic-usage/) shows an example where the user can enter the url and the webview controller loads that url

**Code for loading:**

```
onSubmitted: (value) {
                    var url = Uri.parse(value);
                    if (url.scheme.isEmpty) {
                      url = Uri.parse("https://www.google.com/search?q=" + value);
                    }
//The below given 2 lines are responsible for loading the url
                    webViewController?.loadUrl(
                        urlRequest: URLRequest(url: url));
                  },
```

**Code for web view display:**

```
InAppWebView(
                        key: webViewKey,
                        initialUrlRequest:
                        URLRequest(url: Uri.parse("https://inappwebview.dev/")),
                        initialOptions: options,
                        pullToRefreshController: pullToRefreshController,
                        onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
                          webViewController = controller;
                        },
                        onLoadStart: (controller, url) {
                          setState(() {
                            this.url = url.toString();
                            urlController.text = this.url;
                          });
                        },
                        androidOnPermissionRequest: (controller, origin, resources) async {
                          return PermissionRequestResponse(
                              resources: resources,
                              action: PermissionRequestResponseAction.GRANT);
                        },
                        shouldOverrideUrlLoading: (controller, navigationAction) async {
                          var uri = navigationAction.request.url!;

                          if (![ "http", "https", "file", "chrome",
                            "data", "javascript", "about"].contains(uri.scheme)) {
                            if (await canLaunch(url)) {
                              // Launch the App
                              await launch(
                                url,
                              );
                              // and cancel the request
                              return NavigationActionPolicy.CANCEL;
                            }
                          }

                          return NavigationActionPolicy.ALLOW;
                        },
                        onLoadStop: (controller, url) async {
                          pullToRefreshController.endRefreshing();
                          setState(() {
                            this.url = url.toString();
                            urlController.text = this.url;
                          });
                        },
                        onLoadError: (controller, url, code, message) {
                          pullToRefreshController.endRefreshing();
                        },
                        onProgressChanged: (controller, progress) {
                          if (progress == 100) {
                            pullToRefreshController.endRefreshing();
                          }
                          setState(() {
                            this.progress = progress / 100;
                            urlController.text = this.url;
                          });
                        },
                        onUpdateVisitedHistory: (controller, url, androidIsReload) {
                          setState(() {
                            this.url = url.toString();
                            urlController.text = this.url;
                          });
                        },
                        onConsoleMessage: (controller, consoleMessage) {
                          print(consoleMessage);
                        },
                      ),
```

**Recommendation:**
Go through the documentation. Most of the code does not have to be edited.

Comment: I know how to load the url in the webview. I'm specifically asking `How can I add the option to 'Add to Home screen' functionality`?